# Click image 1 time, get position and destroy window OpenCv

Tags: python, opencv, click, coordinates

Is there a simple way to open an image using OpenCv, and keep it open until it is clicked, then return the pixel coordinate and destroy the image, almost like using WaitKey() just with a return, and click as trigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np

def onClick(event,x,y,flags,param):
    """Called whenever user left clicks"""
    global Running
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        print(f'I saw you click at {x},{y}')
        Running = False

# Create window
wname = "Funky Image"
cv2.namedWindow(winname=wname)
cv2.setMouseCallback(wname, onClick)

# Load an image
img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')

Running = True
while Running:

    cv2.imshow(wname,img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: destroyAllWindows is a function, so for clarity it may be important to add the ()

Comment: @NicholasZolton Thank you - I have added it back - it must have got lost when copy/pasting. Many thanks.